# Do PHP pages on a server run simultaneously?

Tags: php, apache, process

This probably seems like a very simple question, and I would probably know if I had a more in depth knowledge of computer processes and the like, but anyway..

If two people request the same page from my server, is the PHP page processed once for the first person, and then a second time for the second person, or might these run along side each other at the same time?

Take this as an example. I have one stock Item left in my PHP driven online shop. A user adds this to their cart. Php script 1) checks to see if it is in stock, Yup, its in stock, so it 2)reserves it for him.

What If, in between checking if its in stock and reserving it, the same PHP page was loading for someone else, and just after user A checked if it was in stock, so did user B, before user A got a chance to reserve it, so they both end up reserving it!

Sorry if this seems silly, can't seem to find an answer on it, which is it?

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn about transactions...

Comment: Hi, Mick. Please don't sign your posts. Cordially,

Comment: Many thanks for the advice guys.. So just thinking, is there any way I can limit it so only one DB connection can be open at a time? and do this at a database level? If a script tries to open a DB connection, and one is already open, then MYSQL pause before opening the connection.

Comment: Why would you do that instead of doing it the right way?

Comment: Well, I run a fairly quite shop, but I still can't afford to take the risk, so I was wondering If there is something I can implement that won't affect my already in place PHP code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Congratulations, you have identified a [*race condition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)! :-)

Whether PHP pages run in parallel or one after the other depends on the web server. Typically a web server allocates several threads to handle multiple incoming requests at once. So it may indeed happen that several instances of the same script are run in parallel if two or more users request the same page at the same time. Due to timing and scheduling differences it is unpredictable when each page will execute which action exactly.

Hence for such situations as you describe it is important to program actions in an atomic way, meaning that they either complete in their entirety or not at all. In your case you could use locks, transactions, cleverly formed `UPDATE` statements, `UNIQUE` indexes or a number of other techniques that avoid the possibility of two users reserving the same thing.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on "they either complete in their entirety or not at all". How does that help in the context. Two scritpts requesting the same parmeter from a database might still cause a double "in stock" scenario, as described above... Right!?!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in general, without getting into too much detail: **PHP scripts are executed simultanously for each request separately**.

For making sure the problem you mentioned does not occur, you should probably implement feature of your database management system called "**transactions**". This way if you do something on the database layer and at the end you will find out the reservation can not happen, all the actions made within transaction will be rolled back.

In addition to transactions **you should design your application keeping in mind that the problem you mentioned may occur**. Thus you should design your database & application in a way allowing you to 1) shorten the time between "checking" and "reserving" as much as possible, 2) stopping the action if you cannot make reservation, and finally - in case of emergency - 3) identifying which reservation came first and which should be revoked.

Another idea, falling into category of "*your application's design*", may be something we could call "***temporary reservation***". That means you can temporarily (eg. for a couple of seconds) lock your reservation if you are about to make reservation. After that you can check if you really can make that reservation and either turn it into permanent reservation or just revoke it. I believe some systems also make longer temporary reservations right after the customer begins the process of reserving his/her places. Then, if the process is successful, the reservation is changed into permanent, but if some specific amount of time passes without success, the reservation can be simply revoked, allowing another customer to begin the process.

Answer (score -1):

Yes and no. PHP may run in simultaneous processes depending on server setup, but on a small-scale, you'll only have one database. Database queries are handled sequentially, so you'll never have that kind of conflict. (As long as you check to see if an item's in stock immediately before you reserve it for someone.) [More information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4981638/1122351)

Of course, Users A + B might both see that it's in stock, and A might request it before B. But your code can realize that it's now out of stock and display an error to User B.

(You get into trouble with multiple database servers. If you have the same data stored across multiple servers, there's lag time before data can be fully replicated. But you won't have that issue. We're talking like top 1,000 sites here.)

Comment: Well, your *of course* clause is exactly the point of the question and it's caused by scripts running in parallel, even if on a small scale. And database queries are not necessarily handled sequentially, that very much depends on the database.

Comment: php may run those two scripts simultaneously but the one database connection would limit off the problem. the first question should be answered with yes ;)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980801/how-simultaneous-queries-are-handled-in-a-mysql-database.

Answer (score -1):

yes definately, they are parallel for php but when the database concerns you should learn transaction portion of database management system.

Comment: i said there is not need to worry about just only php. but when database concerns you should worry about proper transaction management.

Comment: Yes I know you did -- you've just re-arranged your words. But this is just an assertion.