# Equivalent of oracle's Parallel option in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database-migration

In oracle we can create a table and insert data and select it with parallel option.

Is there any similar option in mysql. I am migrating from oracle to mysql and my system has more select and less data change, so any option to select parallely is what i am seeking for.

eg: Lets consider my table has 1 million rows and if i use parallel(5) option then five threads are running the same query with limit and fetching approximately 200K each and as final result i get 1 million record in 1/5th of usual time.

Answer (score 5):

In short, the answer is no.

The MySQL server is designed to execute concurrent user sessions in parallel, but not to execute one given user session in several parts in parallel.

This is a personal opinion, but I would refrain from wanting to apply optimizations up front, making assumptions about how the RDBMS works. Better measure the query first, and see if the response time is a real concern or not, and only then investigate possible optimizations.

"Premature optimization is the root of all evil." (Donald Knuth)

Answer (score 2):

Queries within MySQL are always run parallel. If you want to run different queries simultaneously through your program, however, you would need to open different connections through workers that your program would have async access to.

You could also run tasks through creating events or using delayed inserts, however I don't think that applies very well here. Something else to consider:

> Generally, some operations are guarded between individual query
>   sessions (called transactions). These are supported by InnoDB
>   backends, but not MyISAM tables (but it supports a concept called
>   atomic operations). There are various level of isolation which differ
>   in which operations are guarded from each other (and thus how
>   operations in one parallel transactions affect another) and in their
>   performance impact. - [Holger Just](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980801/how-simultaneous-queries-are-handled-in-a-mysql-database)

He also mentions the MySQL transcations page, which breifly goes over the different engine types available to MySQL (MyISAM being faster, but not as reliable):
[MySQL Transcations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html)

Comment: FWIW, MyISAM hasn't been faster than InnoDB for a long time (for most workloads).  http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/01/08/innodb-vs-myisam-vs-falcon-benchmarks-part-1/