# MySQL concurrent updates

Tags: mysql

I have small POS system with server side uses PHP and MySql (InnoDB).
When "Sale" is being completed the following query is executed for update stock quantity:

```
"UPDATE products SET qty=qty-:qty, ustatus=1 WHERE pid=:pid";
```

Does this statement is "Concurrency Update Secure", meaning do i need any transactions or locking tables.

I just want to be sure, that multiple queries like this, executed in same time
does not make mess with my stock.

Comment: You can check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980801/how-simultaneous-queries-are-handled-in-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. If you use innodb, then [all sql statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html) are executed in a transaction, you do not need to explicitly specify that.
2. Concurrency control is done via locks, not transactions. Transactions may only determine the lifespan of locks.
3. The update statement places an [exclusive lock on the records that it wants to modify](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html), meaning [no other statements can modify](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_exclusive_lock) (sometimes cannot even read) the locked record until the exclusive lock is released. So, your statement is safe from concurrency point of view.

Comment: Does that mean, while record is locked, the following queries will be placed in queue and executed later anyway?

Comment: Yes, something along these lines. However, the update statement in the question is atomic and you do not seem to have other statements in the transaction, so any locks will only be held for a fraction of a second, so no real queuing will be done.