# How do multiple instances of a python application behave in the case they are updating the same row of SQL DB?

Tags: python, sql, node.js

How will a python program let say three line of code. Will handle changes in some row of a SQL db(mysql) for one user and if at the same time a different user updates the same row in the db at the exact same time. What will happen? Can any one help me. This code is not multithreaded.Thanksn advance

Comment: Python is (somewhat) irrelevant.  It's up to the database how it handles concurrent updates.  `This code is not multithreaded` - Sure it is; the threads are just on different machines.  [That said, your bigger worry is what you want to happen when updates happen _not_ at the same time, from reads that were at the same time](https://www.codemag.com/Article/0607081/Database-Concurrency-Conflicts-in-the-Real-World), because this case is far more common.  How you application handles this issue is up to you.  Did you have a more specific question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL concurrent updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964568/mysql-concurrent-updates)