# Mysql and java : How to handle multiple users when it comes down to concurrent updates

Tags: java, mysql, orm, locking

I've looked pretty much everywhere with terms I know but haven't found any good solution. I'm trying to do a small app that essentially does bookkeeping. I use java for the frontend and MySQL for the database.

The app has to support multiple users (3-4), therefore I want to implement some kind of protection if two users want to edit the same row.

The things I've looked into and the reasons I don't know if I should use them:

- Hibernate: I've seen multiple threads saying ORM are complicating things down the road
- Optimistic/Pessimistic locking: Use hibernate or SELECT ... FOR UPDATE which I've read is bad for concurrency

I don't know what else to look into.

Thank you for reading

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50964971/6803997) will help as a reference? Seems like exclusive locks are placed automatically in MySQL when you execute an UPDATE statement.

Comment: I've read it and it's good on the MySQL side but the users can still all edit the same row at the same time and therefor they will just overwrite their edits since they won't know someone is already editing. Did I get that correctly?

Comment: I believe so? In all honesty I don't have experience with concurrency in regards to MySQL, but wanted to do a bit of research to try to help you.

Comment: Thank you anyway, I didnt know about the implicit lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement some kind of locking the row in the database from your application, e.g. add a column "lockedby" with an identifier for the client as the value. In your application before you grant access to edit the row you check that flag. The application should re-acquire the lock, if the program is still in edit mode, so if the client fails, the row does not stay locked forever. Just an idea, but that's a possible solution, I think.

Another way would be to check if the row has changed before you commit your update to it. Could be easily achieved by checking a hashsum of the contents.

Comment: If I understand correctly the client you mention is the user? If so, I should add the id of the user into a new column when he is trying to modify a row and if it succeeds I can reset the value inserted in the new column? Furthermore if it is the same user he can re-acquire the lock if it is his id in the new column?

Comment: I expected you to have a client which the users are using to get and modify the data on the database. If they all are working on the database directly, meaning you don't have a special client in which you could program the logic, then this method is not appropriate.

Comment: Oh, client as in a software for the users? Yes, that is the scenario. I just meant that they got a session when connecting to the software meaning I can store the user's ID in the lock column.

Comment: Yes that I think that would be a good identifier. I would probably store two fields. One for the id of the user, who locked the row and one for the timestamp. After for example five minutes or so, the look would "expire", meaning the fields would be still present at that time but outdated, so the software client for another user knows, it can give the lock to someone else. This would be the "failure" case, if one client hangs. Normally you would give the lock back, when you are done.

Comment: You are welcome. Hope it helps. Good luck with your solution.