# php slim 3 how make my endpoint accept only one request at a time other requests should be queued

Tags: php, mysql, slim

in php slim 3 framework i want my endpoint accept only one request at a time when first request finished it's processing then the second request should be in process mode and other requests should be queued.

if endpoint gets 2 requests at same time PDO shows this exception
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

```
function addClient($request) {
    $client = json_decode($request->getBody());

    $sql = 'select unique column';

    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(some logic)
         {
            $get_card_query = "insert into another table ";   
            $stmt = $db->prepare($get_card_query);
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $row[0]);
            $stmt->execute();
         }
        $db = null;
    } 

    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Smells to be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: `'select unique column'` is not a valid SQL statement.. So, what are your trying to do ?

Comment: @PeymanMohamadpour: and XY problem? or a [PEBCAK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK) problem?

Comment: @Luuk yes this is just for explaining –

Comment: Solution is here: [MySQL concurrent updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964568/mysql-concurrent-updates)

Comment: If you really can't fix the concurrent update problem, the term to search for is "locking": you can't stop your web server passing the requests to your PHP code, but you can detect if there's a request already holding some form of shared lock, and decide what to do.